# pterodactyl запуск python кода

Tags: python, vds, control-panel

Я бы хотел настроить запуск кода на Python с использованием панели управления Pterodactyl. Можете подсказать, как мне создать 'Egg', который позволит мне запускать Python-код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел в гит хабе установил json и импортировал Egg
https://github.com/pterodactyl-installer/pterodactyl-installer